# POSTFIX and DOVECOT, receving OK sending KO

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have installed postfix and dovecot(1.2.12) with ubuntu.

This is my **main.cf**

```
alias_maps = 
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydomain = example.net
myhostname = mail.example.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_gid_maps = static:5001
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/postfix/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5001
```

this is my **dovecot.conf**

```
protocols = imap imaps

log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "

log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log

mail_privileged_group = vmail

protocol imap {
        mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}

auth default {
        mechanisms = plain login

        # imaps/ smtp user database
        passdb passwd-file {
                args = /home/postfix/vmail/passwd
        }

        # all mail is mapped to this user.
        userdb static {
                args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/home/postfix/vmail/%d/%n
        } 


        user = root
        !include_try /etc/dovecot/auth.d/*.auth
}
dict {
}
plugin {
}
!include_try /etc/dovecot/conf.d/*.conf
```

**(The conf.d/ and auth.d/ are empty)**

I do not see errors on the log, but with this configuration I CAN receive email but I CAN'T send email... I always have this error:

**Relay access denied**

I'm trying to send email from my account to a @gmail.com account

Something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What mail client are you using to send the email, is it configured to use a username and password to send mail?

Comment: yes, I'm using thunderbird

Comment: Is your thunderbird set up to use a username and password?

Comment: @sysadmin1138 yes, i'm using user@mydomain.com and password

Answer (score 1):

Is postfix & dovecot and the email client itself on the same machine?

If not, you need to modify mynetworks to include your IP range.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see you were using SASL. You should test if SASL is working when trying to send email via telnet. There are articles on how to do this..